# Java Regexp to get all Variables from a String

Tags: java, regex

I have a String looking like this:

```
String input = "I have a $personInstance.first_name, but I like    $personInstance.last_name dog better.";
```

I need to validate the variables in the string. How can I parse them out from the text using java regular expression matcher.

Out of the above string I would like to get:

```
personInstance.first_name
personInstance.last_name
```

Does anybody know how to write a the pattern?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("HOW SHOULD THIS LOOK LIKE??");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    List<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found a " + m.group() + ".");
        animals.add(m.group());
    }
```

Comment: Do you know what a valid variable name looks like? Those rules should be pretty straightforward to translate to a regex.

Comment: Good question: It starts with a $ then any character or a dot then any character and then a blank character or a punctuation mark. I tried to show that in the above example.

Comment: What exactly is "any character"? ASCII letters? Unicode letters? Are digits allowed? Even at the start? How about underscores? I see them in variable names all the time...a regex needs to be precise.

Comment: If we just start with "any character" means any sign so including numbers, special characters like "_" once I have a basis I will be able to narrow it down step by step myself. That's what I hope at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straightforward

```
    String input = "I have a $personInstance.address, but I like    $personInstance.last_name dog better.";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\w+\\.\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found a " + m.group(1));
        //use m.group(0) vs m.group(1) if you want $ to be returned as well
    }
```

Explanation:

- `\\$` : match $ (starting with $ as we have it in the beginning)
- `\\w` : match a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _ (underscore)
- `\\.` : match . (dot)
- `()` : capture matches in a group (if you need to remove $ from your output)
- `+` : match it any number of times

Comment: I think this one is better >> ( Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$[^\\s\\,]+"); )
the token may contain characters other than '\\w'

Comment: I assume OP uses the common syntax for variables in most programming languages. Moreover your suggestion will also capture something like this $person.foo1$person.foo2 as one variable and not two as expected.

Comment: You are right, this will solve the adjacent tokens issue:
"\\$[^\\s\\,\\$]+"

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "I have a $person.Instance.address, but I like    $personInstance.last_name dog better.";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$[^\\s\\,\\$]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found a " + m.group());
}
```

**Updated** to "\$[^\s\,\$]+" (to avoid matching adjacent tokens as one)